# Grunt - read json object from file

Tags: json, gruntjs

I want to use [grunt-hash](https://github.com/jgallen23/grunt-hash) plugin for renaming my js files.
This plugin create a new file containing map of renamed files:

```
hash: {
    options: {
        mapping: 'examples/assets.json', //mapping file so your server can serve the right files
```

Now I need to fix links to this files by replacing all usages (rename 'index.js' to 'index-{hash}.js') so I want to use [grunt-text-replace](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-text-replace) plugin.
According to documentation I need to cofigure replacements:

```
replace: {
  example: {
     replacements: [{
       from: 'Red', // string replacement
       to: 'Blue'
     }]
   }
}
```

How could I read json mapping file to get {hash} values for each file and provide them to replace task?

Comment: @Future reader: If you just want to read in a file, use [`grunt.file.read`](https://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.read)

Answer (score 26):

```
grunt.file.readJSON('your-file.json')
```

is probably what you are looking for.

I've set up a little test. I have a simple JSON file 'mapping.json', which contains the following JSON object:

```
{
  "mapping": [
    {"file": "foo.txt"},
    {"file": "bar.txt"}
  ]
}
```

In my Gruntfile.js I've written the following simple test task, which reads the first object in the 'mapping'-array:

```
grunt.registerTask('doStuff', 'do some stuff.', function() {
  mapping = grunt.file.readJSON('mapping.json');
  grunt.log.write(mapping.mapping[0]["file"]).ok();
});
```

When invoking the Grunt task, the console output will be as follows:

```
$ grunt doStuff
Running "doStuff" task
foo.txtOK

Done, without errors.
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Is that possible to provide `mapping` variable to replace task? Or extract to global variable.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the replace task correctly, but wouldn't it be possible to read the JSON file from within said replace task?

Comment: I've just updated my question. Please look at configuration of replace task.

Comment: To be honest, this looks oddly complicated and error prone to me, don't you agree? How about a solution as explained in [this blog post](http://robandlauren.com/2013/08/14/busting-cache-with-grunt/)?

Comment: There is one hash value for all files in this solution. If one file changed - you reset all cache in application. I want to create hash for each file separately. Thats possible but how to set links to this files?

Comment: Correct, that isn't very useful. How about this one? https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-cache-breaker